# How to get number of lines in a file in spring batch in Item reader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring. I have a Job where it reads the file and writes to the Database. If the number of records in the file are more than 8000, i should not process the file and is hould stop the Job Execution. Please suggest what is the better way to do this.

Comment: I am trying to implement conditional step, but not sure how to configure that in code.

Answer (score 2):

you can implement StepExecutionListener at itemreader. Then you can get readcount which is corresponds your line number.

```
 public class ExampleItemReader implements ItemReader<String>, StepExecutionListener {

    public synchronized String read() throws Exception {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution executionContext) {
        if (executionContext.getReadCount() > 8000) {
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
        }
        return ExitStatus.EXECUTING;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {

    }

}
```

advise reading [spring batch patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html)

Comment: This is not exactly what OP wants because this solution process the file and OP wants to discard all records if count is > 8K! With with solution (no tricks to count records faster) probably is better to create a previous step, check for 8K condition (just read record, without writes) and after use a [`JobExecutionDecider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) to check if job need to be continued or completed (this should make the job flow cleaner)

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. If a process is not necessary for files that have over 8K lines, a previous step will better.

Answer (score 1):

Not something specific to spring but there is a class `LineNumberReader` in `java.io`. You can make use of it and its `skip` method to skip a good amount of chars.

Example:

```
public int getNoOfLines(String fileName) {
   LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(fileName));
   reader.skip(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //skips those many chars, if you feel your file size may exceed you can use Long.MAX_VALUE
   return reader.getLineNumber();
}
```

This is efficient than just reading the file and counting.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I am trying implement a parent step for my Job, there i will determine the number of lines and how to stop the job if the parent step completed.

Comment: if you can get hold of the file in your parent step, you can call above method and know the number of lines in that file

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the records in your file are not fixed length. If so, File.length() will easily calculate the number of records in the file.

If not, does it need to be exactly 8000 or around 8000? If it's a rough limit, I would get an average record length for these files and then use File.length() to estimate the number of records.